# Illegal mix of collations in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, encoding, sequelize.js, collation

I have recently update mysql to version 8.0 and I am facing an error.

I have a query that is UNION between a few tables. When I run it directly in CLI everything works fine, but my node app cannot run it with sequelize. This is the error I get

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'
```

Is there any setting in sequelize that can solve this issue?

Comment: convert the columns in question to the right collation, or change the table/columns, why do you have different collations anyway?

Comment: @nbk I don't know why it is giving the error. It is all fine in CLI. How can I convert them?

Comment: show me your tables with create tables and the query

Comment: How do you connect to the database? The charset and collation should be set there. What is the charset and collation of the text/char columns involved in the union?

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for your comments. The issue in the union was with the output of SQL functions. I changed them and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you convert a text into anothe4r charcterset and collation

```
SELECT CONVERT('test' USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
SELECT CONVERT('test', CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
SELECT CAST('test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

So you would make something like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1
> (
>     c1 CHAR(10)
> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t2
> (
>     c1 CHAR(10) 
> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci
> ```

> ```
> SELECT c1 FROm t1
> UNION
> SELECT c1 FROm t2
> ```
>
> ```
> Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONVERT(c1, CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci FROm t1
> UNION
> SELECT c1 FROm t2
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONVERT(c1, CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b11d2b0a63b3bef7e9b7a70f0063b7a3)*

Comment: Please lean toward the 8.0 default utf8mb4 and away from latin1.